# Facebook Share Button in iFrames

Tags: html, facebook-sharer

I have a website that displays news items in a list using php and mysql.
You can see at:

http://www.teambathbuccaneers.co.uk/index.php?page=News.php

I want to be able to add a Facebook share logo/link on each item so that when a user clicks the share button just that one article appears on their own Facebook wall.

I have used the information provided on the Facebook developer pages to create a test but the initial test shows the outer frame and not the inner iframe.

Any advice most welcome on how to make something that will display a single news item.

Thanks.

M

Comment: Could you provide sample of your implementation? Seems like you didn't add needed attributes to it.

Comment: <div style='float:left;padding:5px 5px 5px 0;'> <a expr:share_url='data:post.url' href='http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php' name='fb_share' type='box_count'>Share</a><script src='http://static.ak.fbcdn.net/connect.php/js/FB.Share' type='text/javascript'></script>

Comment: First of all this implementation seems like legacy one. Also, what do you mean by "outer frame" and "inner frame"?

Comment: If you open the website teambathbuccaneers.co.uk you will see that the page has an iframe and all the pages on the site are displayed in that iframe. When I used the implementation of the script above it displayed data about the outer page rather than the page in the iframe despite the script being on the iframe....

Comment: Ok, so your implementation is outdated. you should use new one with: data-href attribute on like element, as provided in this example: 
<div class="fb-like" data-href="http://wp.pl" data-send="true" data-width="450" data-show-faces="true"></div>

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/

Answer (score 0):

Go to : https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/share-button/  -> Get Code  -> iFrame.

Enter the link where you display the item detail page, which must contain a unique identifier, you will see that inside the iframe tag :

```
                          src="https://www.facebook.com/plugins/share_button.php?href=https%3A%2F%{{  your url }}%2F{{  detail-page  }}%2F{{  unique-identifier  }}&layout=button_count&size=large&appId=243300912962319&width=150&height=22"width="150" height="22" style="border:none;overflow:hidden" scrolling="no"frameborder="0" allowTransparency="true" allow="encrypted-media">
```